# Change auto increment value if a duplicate exist from another table

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I am trying to generate a temporary ID for a student registration process, for applicants who do not have a specified identity document. However, there were instances when the some applicants used arbitrary ID numbers which are in the series we have selected for official temporary ID number generation.

When I create a temporary ID (via the `c_nic` table), I need to check whether that ID is already used by an applicant (in the `a_student` table) and if yes, skip that number to the next number in `c_nic`, so on and forth. I am using the `auto_increment` of the temporary ID table (`c_nic`)

e.g. When a student comes in for registration and he doesn't have an ID number, we will generate a temporary ID for him. This will be the auto_increment in the `c_nic` table. Say, *11001111*. Before releasing this ID for the student's use, I need to check whether this has been used by another student by mistake. If *11001111* is used by another student for his registration, I need to give the current student the next available ID, which may be *11001112* or if that is also used *11001113* and so on. When the new student is given the new temporary ID, I need to adjust the auto_inc value in the `c_nic` table, so that the second new student gets the next available ID number.

I tried with the following code, but the auto_increment does not increase even if there is a records already exists in the `a_students` table

```
$refid = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` AS id FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '".DB_NAME."' AND TABLE_NAME = 'c_nic'");
$refnum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($refid);
$ref = $refnum["id"];   
$refnew = $refnum["id"]+1;  
$chkduplicate = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nic FROM a_students WHERE nic='$ref'");
do {
    $chkduplicate = mysqli_query($conn, "ALTER TABLE c_nic AUTO_INCREMENT = '$refnew'");
$refnew = $refnum["id"]+1;
echo '<br/>Ref: '.$ref;
echo '<br/>Ref New: '.$refnew;
}
while (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) >0 );
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do and how your temporary ID registration should work. Messing around with the AUTO_INCREMENT value is not a good idea. Explain why you just can't use the generated AUTO_INCREMENT id as normal.

Comment: @Progman I just did. I do no need to generate auto ID. I am thinking of increasing the ID if it cannot be used for the purpose.

Comment: Why do you not give IDs from the same AUTO_INCREMENT column for all the students? Why split into temporary and non-temporary students, specially when you check for used IDs anyway?

Comment: @Progman because most students **do** have IDs. This is their student ID as well. But young kids *do not* have state-issued IDs. They do not have a way get registered with the courses, rather than using an arbitrary ID. I do not want to give someone an arbitrary ID which is already in use by another student.

Comment: Why do you not give the students so called "student numbers" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campus_card), which are not related to the state-issued ID? The state-issued ID would just be a column in the students table and will be `NULL` for temporary students (like kids).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use table as auto increment & primary key for unique student id
like below

```
ALTER TABLE a_students
ADD PRIMARY KEY (nic);
ALTER TABLE a_students AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```